# Mac Preview's map imagery owned by NASA?

Tags: macos, mac, preview, copyright, geotagging

When you open the About box of Preview, it says

> Preview
>
> Version 5.0
>
> Map imagery owned by NASA
>
> [NASA's Earth Observatory](http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/)
>
> Copyright © 2002–2009 Apple Inc.
>
> All rights reserved.

What map imagery? There is a simple world map in the Info page for geotagged photos, much like the one you use to set your timezone (and it links to Google Maps). Is that it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. The accreditation in the About box is for showing the GPS location of a photo and that's all.

Comment: If that is all, I wonder why they could not find a free map (or use the one from the timezone preference pane). With all the intellectual property involved in writing an image/video/document preview app, it is weird that only this silly map gets credits.

Comment: The one from the Time zone preference pane is from NASA as well, and as far as I know (could very well be wrong) the NASA images *are* free but just require you to state that they came from NASA. Most of the IP bits you'd allude to are actually in frameworks (so they can be used by other applications) used by Preview and not Preview itself.